# Question put on hold for absolutely no reason

Tags: discussion, moderation, on-hold

The question described below has been put on hold for reasons beyond my understanding. Would someone please kindly explain why?  I would like to start discussion on this if possible:

https://stackoverflow.com/q/39667486

### Title of the question:

> Why does python use ** instead of ^ to represent exponentiation?

### Content of the question:

> **Who this question is addressed to:**  People who have significant background in theory of design and implementation of programming languages and therefore have very good intuition on why certain choices in design of programming languages may be favored over others.
>
> **why this question is not opinion based:**  Because just like there is a good reason for why other features of language are structure the way they are. (certain feature of language being based on fortran and c++ and therefore being largely very efficient) similarly this may perhaps be one of those things where efficiency is impacted. or may be not at all. but the question if being dismissed for completely wrong reasons. Below is the question:
>
> what consideration in internal representation made architect of the language to choose ** over ^? or was it a pure having preference for certain kind of notation thing?

Comment: Your "similar question" is on a _different site_ with a _different scope._ Note that I do not know the scope of the other site myself, so I cannot say your question would fit over here. But you can't point to a different site and say, "This question fit, so why does my question get closed?!" If you're going to pick an example, pick a _recent_ example from SO. Programmers has different scope.

Comment: Putting the different question aside for a moment, which rule does my question not abide by?

Comment: I explained thoroughly that per the rules of stack overflow contents of the question fit in thoroughly. I truly don't understand why this question might be out of scope. there's no reason for it to be. It is a genuinely well crafted programming languages question.

Comment: Because we it is considered opinion based by our scope. You would need the architect of the language, as you worded it, to tell you why, or you would need a statement from that architect. Otherwise, it's going to be best guesses and opinions that you get. It is incredibly unlikely that you'll get a good answer to that question here. There have been meta discussions about this type of question specifically, let's see if one can be located quick.

Comment: Note that per your explanation, you actually don't prove that it's on topic. Just because there are good reasons for other features being selected as they were does not mean that there are good reasons for the one you asked about, nor that people know why they were selected. It would require some sort of insight from the creator of the language, and unless they put out something that can easily be found, it's just incredibly unlikely that you'll get an answer that isn't people guessing.

Comment: All it takes for me to get an answer is people of good expertise in design of programming languages. That's it. does stack overflow expect to not have this kind of expertise?

Comment: Stack overflow has people who have expertise in all kinds of advanced cs topics, except for programming languages? is this what we are saying?

Comment: Look if this question would be easily answerable I would find it myself. I would not go to stack overflow to ask a very advanced programming languages design question. the very reason I am asking this question if because it's not easily googleable. It not googleable at all. that's why i am looking for people who have advanced expertise in design of programming languages to gain insight into it. that's all.

Comment: What I'm/we're saying is that _we can guess._ We can make educated guesses, sure, but they'll still be guesses unless the creator _says_ they did something for such and such reason. Even if our guesses are 100% sound and make the most sense... The creator could have made their decision for a completely different reason. _They are guesses._ They are not 100% fact. People won't vote on what is correct, they will vote on what they like most. This will be mostly because we _can't_ validate what is the correct guess. It doesn't boil down to expertise, it boils down to _facts_ versus _guesses_.

Comment: This isn't an advanced programming language design question. The language designer chose a symbol. That's it. Also, it turns out [your question is a duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23230726/1288), so it is easily answerable by Googling.

Comment: @BilltheLizard good. That is one obvious explanation. And looks like it's a pure convention thing. but can't dismiss a question like the way it was being dismissed. May be it was the language creator just choose the symbol may be not. per this it looks like just a convention: en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation#In_programming_langua‌​ges

Comment: It definitely is a question of why certain convention in design of programming languages may be favored another

Comment: is it not? or am I missing something?

Comment: @gnas Especially opinionated stuff is kept in the eye of the beholder.

Comment: FWIW, exponentiation isn't a very common operation you do in code, so reserving a single-character token for it may not be the best option, as it would prevent you from using `^` for some other future language feature (let's assume xor didn't exist at the time the decision was made). From a language design standpoint it makes sense to use short tokens for common operations and longer tokens for the less common ones. Still, this is just my... opinion ;-)

Answer (score 30):

It has been put on hold because you are asking us to take a wild stab at why Guido van Rossum chose certain operators to have certain characters.

Now we could come up with a wide range of reasons. Perhaps even well-motivated ones. Maybe we assume influences from other languages. Maybe we can infer something from the author's background. That's all moot if in the end he just lost his keys the very day he took this decision and just in anger decided to mash some keys on the keyboard to see what he would end up with. (We all know that losing your keys can make you do crazy stuff).

Even you yourself say *"May be it was the language creator just choosing the symbol may be not."* In absence of this creator, we can only guess. And that makes the question unfit for Stack Overflow.

And even if eventually Guido would be so kind to hop on to the site and answer the question, I'd argue it's nothing more than trivia.

Comment: Don't know how many times to repeat this. If there are a few programming language design experts who have a good, intuitive grasp for how choices like this are made in the design of programming languages, the would probably be able to give an accurate answer. Id assume it's probably tirvia as well. but the question should have never been put on hold in my opinion. It's wrong to shoot down a very well targeted question.

Comment: how about this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19722552/why-linux-kernel-uses-something-like-u16-two-underbars

Comment: There are plenty of users here who could give you accurate guesses. Heck, I'd say you have received some good ones. And one of the moderators arguing it's still all conjecture isn't all that terrible when it comes to Python himself. It's a question that, in absence of the benevolent dictator himself, amounts to flinging spaghetti at a wall to see what will stick. We can all take reasonable stabs at it, one answer not better than the other. All in all it does not fit the scope.

Comment: @gnas because it fell under the radar.

Comment: the question I just posted is no different in nature than mine. It's still out there with people taking stabs at it. is this not true?

Comment: It's question from 2013 that has gone largely unnoticed. That doesn't affect the evaluation of your question.

Comment: @gnas No, that question is no different in nature from yours. I voted to close it as well. But no, people are not still taking stabs at it. It hasn't had activity since the day it was asked. We really don't want questions that are going to sit unanswered for years, hence the close votes.

Comment: @gnas We don't like questions whose answers will end up as a popularity contest because we can't confirm their correctness. (Popularity contest between two verifiabley correct coding solutions is a bit different, at least in my mind.) The question you just posted is 3 years old, and has not had any activity since it was posted. Stack Overflow gets thousands of questions a day, and has for a while. It's entirely possible that the right people did not see that question while yours was spotted. (I wouldn't be surprised if the one you linked gets closed before long.)

Comment: @BilltheLizard how is it different in nature? there's good rational reason both for why linux used __u16 and why the decision was made to use ** instead ^. I still have a hard time grasping why this question is being considered out of scope. Haven't heard a good single answer so far. My question has a well defined target for who might answer it, I gave the intuition for why it is a good question. So far i haven't heard a good argument from the other side.

Comment: other than vague justifications like scope is different. What do you mean scope is different? No this question doesn't violate any guidelines on scope. I apologize.

Comment: @gnas It is not different in nature, as I said. You have received several good arguments, you're just ignoring them.

Comment: Bottom line: we like questions that have a clearly defined correct answer. In some occasions it could even end up having multiple verifiable correct answers. However ... your question invites guesses. Educated guesses. Well-argued guesses. Well-motivated guesses. But still guesses. That's the difference.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13390401/design-of-python-why-is-assert-a-statement-and-not-a-function           how about this?

Comment: do you not like this question as well?

Comment: @BilltheLizard http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13390401/design-of-python-why-is-assert-a-statement-and-not-a-function this question

Comment: @Bart  this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13390401/design-of-python-why-is-assert-a-statement-and-not-a-function

Comment: @Kendra   this question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13390401/design-of-python-why-is-assert-a-statement-and-not-a-function

Comment: how is this question different than mine? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13390401/design-of-python-why-is-assert-a-statement-and-not-a-function

Comment: @gnas please stop that. There is no need to ping us with whatever other question you find. We have given you the reasons you asked for.

Comment: does this question not invite Educated guesses, Well-argued guesses, Well-motivated guesses?

Comment: @Bart let me repeat myself, so far there hasn't been even a single good argument for my question being put on hold. and you can observe the question I posted is absolutely similar in nature and was well received. different rules for different questions?

Comment: @Bart the very arguments used by you just collapse in consideration of the question  link to which I just posted.

Comment: I would argue it isn't similar in nature. The question you linked just now has a clear answer given the very  nature of how you expect an assert to behave, and what side-effects you'd like to avoid. I'd say your question doesn't fit that bill. So while at first glance you may want to throw them into the same pool, I don't think that's correct. But whatever my view on that question, I'm not sure it's worth our time to dig up random questions to compare them with yours. If you don't like my answer, wait for another answer or point of view.

Comment: @gnas "Are there any advantages to having assert be a statement (and reserved word) instead of a function?" is quite different than asking why one symbol was chosen over another. Read the answers to that question. It's not just a matter of preference, or influence from other languages.

Comment: @Bart expecting is guessing or in other words the question invited a guess into the answer. Therefore by the very standards posed by you this question either should be unacceptable because it is very similar in nature to mine or both of them should be accepted.

Comment: Nah, now you're just twisting my words. At this point I'd suggest we simply agree to disagree.

Comment: @gnas why do you care about someone else's question. You asked why **your** question was put on hold, and you were given the (many) reasons why. If you want some kind of action to be taken against _another_ question then go and vote for it to be closed or raise a separate meta post. No answer can be given to your question that is based on facts and facts alone, and so it is off-topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: @BilltheLizard beg to disagree. Both answers have definite grounding in facts. May be the group of people attempting to answer doesn't have a good grasp of those very fundamental facts that undermine decisions made in one and the other scenario. That doesn't mean that those two questions are different in nature. Because they are not. it's a fallacy to think in this manner.

Comment: @Bart  I am absolutely not. It is literally right there. You may skim through the conversation we were having.

Comment: People, the question I just posted a link to is being held to different set of rules than my question. I really doubt that anyone one of you can doubt that. That's just not arguable.

Comment: @gnas It is being held to the same set of rules. Your question is just inferior. Can't argue with that.

Comment: The fact that this meta post has so many down votes should give you an insight into how many people are trying to tell you that you're wrong. Just accept it and move on instead of fighting a losing battle.

Comment: @BilltheLizard   teach me about superiority and inferiority of questions, please :-)

Comment: @gnas Some things can't be taught, apparently.

Comment: Tim Post lost his keys so I decided to upvote this answer. Crazy stuff, indeed.

Comment: @BilltheLizard right, right :-) I think you should stay strong. Though I've demonstrated  vividly how much bias people capable of, we can all get though this.

Answer (score 18):

You have asked for what rule your question broke, what guideline it does not fit. You do not accept that your question is opinion based even though all the answers will be, except in an extremely unlikely situation, guesses.

So let's actually take a look at the help center, shall we?

We'll start with the [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) page:

> - a specific programming problem, or
> - a software algorithm, or
> - software tools commonly used by programmers; and is
> - a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development

Your question is not a specific programming problem. It is not about a software algorithm. There's no software tool being asked about.

As we have been trying to tell you, it is *not* an answerable problem that is unique to software development. All the "answers" will be guesses, *not* answers.

If this still does not back up what has been said here, allow me to add from the [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) page:

> - inspire answers that explain “why” and “how”
> - tend to have long, not short, answers
> - have a constructive, fair, and impartial tone
> - invite sharing experiences over opinions
> - insist that opinion be backed up with facts and references
> - are more than just mindless social fun

You're only asking for answers that explain why, so you do not run afoul of that point. We don't know how long the answers would be, so hard to say there. I wouldn't argue about your tone, personally.

It's the next two points where issues arise. The answers will be *opinions* of why it was chosen as it was, at least more than likely, and it is very safe to assume they will also not be backed up with facts and references. These two points very clearly indicate that your question is opinion based. Answers will not be backed up with facts, they will be guesses and opinions.

Therefore, the question is off-topic on Stack Overflow. That other questions managed to fly under the radar does not mean that your question is okay, it just means they hadn't been caught yet.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13390401/design-of-python-why-is-assert-a-statement-and-not-a-function   this is an opinion based question as well, and only the designer of the language knows why assert is a statement not a function. And it still is a good question. Well received and not on hold. why is that?

Comment: @gnas 2 wrongs don't make a right.  Once again, please don't point to old questions as evidence for current policies.  More importantly, there is an actual (slightly broad) question that is directly answerable: "Are there any advantages to having assert be a statement (and reserved word) instead of a function?"  That isn't opinion-based like the other question.

Comment: Beg to disagree. My question is just as much of "Are there any advantages of having ** represent exponentiation in python over ^ represent exponentiation"

Comment: how about that?

Comment: @gnas that _isn't_ your question though.... and even if it was, it would **still** be off-topic because it would be opinion-based

Comment: Those two questions are logically equivalent.

Comment: Now you're just being contrarian.  Read Kendra's answer again, specifically the part that good open-ended questions "tend to have long, not short, answers" and "have a constructive, fair, and impartial tone"

Comment: It's just wrong to hold one question up to one set of standards and other to a different set of standards. just wrong.

Comment: And we have told you multiple times that is not the case. Now, that you're not willing to accept that is another matter.

Comment: @bart yes that is the case, I vividly demonstrated that one genuinely opinion based question (the one about assert statements) got a green light and another one (mine) got shot down. This is wrong. very wrong.

Comment: @gnas From the [same page Kendra linked](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) to:  "__Some subjective questions are allowed, but “subjective” does not mean “anything goes”. All subjective questions are expected to be constructive__" followed by the list you see in this answer.  Kendra demonstrates how your question got a red light because it failed some crucial criteria.

Comment: @ryanyuyu The assert statement question should've gotten a red light as well, if it would have been held up to the same standards and considered from same angles. These two questions are no different in nature. I haven't gotten a single convincing argument that they are. Because they are exactly the same kind of questions, it's just that one was being moderated by one group of folks who had different biases (and were therefore better receptive of the question) and other by different group of folks. That's it.

Comment: @gnas and that's why moderation here is based on votes. If everything were so cut and dry we wouldn't need humans moderating questions.

Comment: The fact that bunch of you moderators, who've known each other for a long time are ganging up on me, and giving me some baloney arguments as to what I know for sure is true as false,   doesn't bother me even slightly.

Comment: @gnas mind sharing which of the bullet points for a good subjective question the other question failed to meet?  It absolutely rocked bulletpoint 4: "invite sharing experiences over opinions" with practical examples of `#define` optimizations.

Comment: mine invites experience of programming language designers who have had experience of designing languages and have made those kind of choices in the past. Do you think there is a problem of inviting this kind of experience into a question asked?

Comment: just to be clear, no one is 'ganging up' on you, but by not accepting _anything_ that anyone is trying to tell you, you're doing a very good job of alienating yourself.

Comment: `Do you think there is a problem of inviting this kind of experience into a question asked?` in a general question, no. On Stack Overflow, yes, because that's not what this site is for.

Comment: @MacroMan  but ryanyuyu's argument says that that's ok for the other question to do, on stack over flow, why is that not ok for my question?

Comment: @gnas It's not just ryanyuyu, many other people have tried to explain it to you in all sorts of ways - the issue now is that you're simply not willing to accept anyone's opinion on the matter other than your own but unfortunately that's just not the way life works. No amount of disagreeing with everything that has been said to you is going to make your question okay, it's been closed because the **community** agreed that it was off-topic, not just one person. Life is unfair, take it as a lesson and just move on.

Comment: @MacroMan   please, don't try to alter my worldview, I feel very comfortable with how I see things :-) I still haven't heard an argument which would hold up to a slight amount of criticism with respect to why my question was shot down, and other one was not. Pure bias. that's it. May be we could call it a group bias. whatever :-)

Comment: @MacroMan People trying to philosophize over me :-D haha and you even admit it that "it is unfair" (Life is unfair piece of your previous comment) which is just too funny.

Comment: @gnas yes it's group bias - the whole SO community just decided all at the same time after talking to each other in secret that we simply prefer another user to yourself. It was nothing to do with your question being off-topic at all.... is that what you want to hear? Because it **still** isn't going to make your question on-topic for this site. I'm not trying to philosophise or change your world view - I'm simply and bluntly putting it to you that you're wrong, and you are unable to accept that.

Comment: I apologize for the expression.

Comment: @gnas well on behalf of Stack Overflow I'm sorry that you feel that way. But it is what it is, nothing is going to change and so I guess you are just going to have to decide how to deal with that in your own way.

Comment: @MacroMan who gave you the right to talk on behalf of stack overflow?

Comment: @gnas that would be the right to freedom of speech my friend, however that has nothing to do with this conversation and at this point I genuinely think you just want somebody to talk to - alas, it's late here and I need to sleep so I bid you farewell and hope that you can perservere through this journey to the light at the other end of the tunnel.

Comment: @macroMan DUDE DO NOT LET GNAS KNOW OF OUR MEETING. THAT WAS RULE 1. On a more serious note(@gnas) pointing to old questions as proof that your question should be accepted doesn't work. Our rules evolve often, and when they do, some questions which were previously okay do not get closed simply because we dont look at old stuff. There is a good chance the examples you link to now receive proper moderation and end up closed .

Comment: @gnas sure... You're aware the Q you linked on the other answer IS closed by now?how is that pure baloney? You showed another question and said "that one is as bad as mine".... Well that one is closed. Dude you may not like it,but that's how the site works. You can stomp your feet (you've demonstrated that already), but not much will change there. The assert statement vs function has an answer linking into compilation and how it works. That wouldn't be the same case between ** and ^.