# Is it possible to get the raw Markdown of a post in-browser without trying to edit it?

Tags: feature-request, edits, markdown, formatting

I'm writing some notes down for myself, and these notes involve citing parts of a Stack Overflow post with a lot of Markdown. Manually copying the text and pasting it into my notes does not preserve the formatting, so I have to recreate it manually.

As an alternative, I *could* click Edit, copy the Markdown, and close the tab without actually proposing any edits...except the particular answer I'd like to copy text from has a full edit queue.

**Is there a way to copy the Markdown of a post in-browser (as opposed to the API)?** If not, consider it a feature request.

Comment: Go to [the post's revisions page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P6g6g.png), then click ["Source" on the most recent revision](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K9T2G.png), which will take you to a bare [page with nothing but the post's Markdown](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/05b25315-73c3-4786-8824-b53bb78cb604/view-source). If the post hasn't had any edits, you can still access the revisions page by taking the post's ID from its share dialogue, and go to `https://{site}/posts/{post_id}/revisions`.

Comment: This is functionally a dupe of this request: [See underlying (Markdown) source code of locked answer/question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/336254/see-underlying-markdown-source-code-of-locked-answer-question)

Comment: @zcoop98 That question wasn't on the suggested alternatives list when I posted this one. Thank you, though.